# Circuit for auto power off

Tags: circuit-design, automation

I am looking for a circuit that can power off automatically after some time (i.e., ten minutes, but accuracy is not important here).

When the circuit cuts the power, the power consumption should be as close to zero as possible.

I have found a lot using google, but they all depend on a push-button, that will give a short input and then leave the circuit on for the desired time.
Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=auto+power+off+circuit

My problem is that I get the power from and ON/OFF switch, and it is when it's left ON, I still need the power to cut off after these ten minutes.

It is for toys and other battery-driven accessories, that children and mind-wandering people (including myself) leave ON by accident.

For reference, I already have a multi-meter that acts this exact way, so it must be possible to do.

Edit: @Andyaka Certainly. How do I make a circuit that shut off automatically after a couple of minutes, but is operated by an ON/OFF switch that keep providing power?

Example: I have a LED, powered by 5 V through an ON/OFF switch.
When I turn the switch ON, the LED turns on.
After ~10 minutes, the LED should turn off, and the system as a whole should hereafter use zero to "almost no" power.
To start the LED again, I turn off the switch, and then turn it ON again. The LED should now emit light for the next ten minutes again.

How do I make a circuit that does this?

Comment: Can you specifically ask a question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to rabidly plagiarize from [another author here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321390):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy1AXM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If that's a \$20\:\text{mA}\$ LED, anyway.

Make sure to require the use of a momentary switch in the above circuit.

When ***off*** the circuit draws no power at all. The MOSFET is key to that fact.

I set \$R_1\$ so that it draws about \$4\:\text{mA}\$ from \$Q_1\$'s base. This probably means the load should be less than about \$25\times\$ more, or less than \$100\:\text{mA}\$ for predictable behavior and zero thermal concerns. The [ZTX751](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZTX751.pdf) can be used without thermal concern up to \$200\:\text{mA}\$ and perhaps to \$500\:\text{mA}\$. But \$R_1\$ may still need to be reduced in value to increase \$Q_1\$'s base current.

Add another diode? And you get re-triggerability with this circuit. (Restarts the timer with a button-press while it is still counting down the time.) \$D_2\$ is what discharges things quickly. So do ***not*** forget to include it. (\$D_1\$ is less critical.)

I first noticed this circuit more than 2 decades ago. And I owe its author for time well-given then. It's practical. Consider it.

Comment: Thank you, but it looks to me on the right side, a diode is connected directly from +5V to GND while SW1 is ON...?

Comment: @MadsAggerholm That could be my misreading of your question. I thought you'd indicated you have an LED that was designed already for 5V. You are correct, though, too. And I'm glad you asked about it. Yes, include a series resistor for the LED. I'll update the schematic when i later get a chance. On phone right now.

Comment: @MadsAggerholm I updated the schematic and slightly changed the text.

Comment: Thank you, but as I see it, the load has permanent power when SW1 is on?
I may have been unclear in my description, but what I need is something that will turn off after a period of time when the switch remain in ON position.
This seem to do the opposite: Keep it on for a period of time when the switch goes from ON to OFF(?)

Comment: My goal is for the power to the load to be switched off after a period of time, *when the switch remains in ON position*.
It is something I want to put into various  battery-driven objects, so they don't use up their batteries when you forget to switch them off after use.

Comment: @MadsAggerholm I now see. I suggest you replace that switch then. A momentary is what you need.

Comment: I think that it is not what is requested, but the solution is in this direction.  It should have a capacitor that charges slowly, when it reaches the maximum voltage level a mosfet cuts the power rail.  Then another mosfet discharges the capacitor to reset the timing only when the switch is turned off, so when there is no power between the switch and the first mosfet.  Also, when the user touches any button of the device (in a more general case) the capacitor should be discharged, to reset the timing.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is that it assumes the device (toy) can be turned off prior to the expiration of the timer. This might be achieved by a second, perhaps long, press of a momentary switch, or with a toggle (perhaps slider) switch. While I think a microcontroller would serve nicely as the timing mechanism, here is an analog solution that uses a (double throw) toggle (perhaps slider) switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftIdhA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit has several problems. The first is the turn off characteristics of the MOSFET. Since the auto-turn-off is based upon the slow discharge of a capacitor, M1 does not turn off sharply. We can model this in CircuitLab by using a relay and a piece-wise-step function generator, like so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fssb8v.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

The second problem is related to the spread of threshold voltages for M1. Here are the waveforms for \$V_T\$ equal to 0.8 V and 1.5 V. The maximum on time varies quite a bit due to variations in M1's threshold voltage.

[image]
[image]

The first problem can be mitigated by driving a second transistor with the drain of M1 and having the 2nd transistor drive the load.

The second problem might possibly be mitigated by finding a MOSFET with a different range of threshold voltages, although I am not too optimistic that much improvement can be made in this area.

A third "problem" is that this solution requires 2 large capacitors. Unfortunately, the resistor in the RC pair cannot be increased much. If bulk is an issue, a microcontroller can eliminate the need for large capacitors.

Comment: I'm curious why this was down-voted.